# Galaxy XCover 6 Pro not connecting to computer via USB

Tags: samsung, usb, file-transfer, android-13

I am currently having difficulties in connecting my Galaxy XCover 6 Pro to a computer.  When I plug it in, it charges for about 1-2 seconds, and then the charging stops.  The computer never registers a device being plugged in, and I do not get the prompt on the phone to switch from charging mode to file transfer mode.  I have tried multiple different cables, multiple different USB ports, and both Windows 10 and Windows 7 computers, and there is no difference in the experience.  The phone does charge fine, so long as the charging cable is plugged into a USB wall charger. The phone is running Android version 13.  Is this an issue other folks are having?  Searching for help on the internet does not show any similar problems for other folks, nor any applicable solutions.

Comment: When connected to an  USB charger, is the charging speed as expected? Based on your description a (partially) defect USB socket on the device may be the cause. It is a common problem that people put too much force on the USB plug while inserted in the phone (in all directions) which can lead to breaking the soldering points the USB socket is connected to the motherboard and then the USB connection is getting unstable (some times only power, or only data or often for both).

Comment: @Robert when connected to the wall wart it will charge without interruption.  It probably takes about 2 hours to go from empty to full, but I have turned rapid charging off in order to preserve the battery, so this time does not seem excessive.

Comment: The the pins that transfer power seem to work correctly, unfortunately this may be different for the data pins. The only way to be sure would be letting a repair center check the device.

Comment: Either your port is damaged or you have charge only cables.